# google spreadsheets bug during appending new rows

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Script must log postback information about call detail from zvonok.com to google spreadsheets. I has write function which only append row to sreadsheet - **no update or modify** of any cell in code and during few manual test calls rows has been append correct, but when my client began his usual call campaign, calls and postbacks going very often one after other, values in last row began changing few times and in some cases leave strange values

I seen behavior like this first time made short video record:
https://youtu.be/0_H_mVAbp4g

here is one column with strange value

- 2103052006092385
- 2,10305E+15
- 210305412464544

I have found 9 cases from 248 rows.
Client has show me excel from his user cabinet, totally was maded 5649 calls, so in google spreadsheets must be 5649 rows instead 248.

```
function getJsonFromUrl(url) {
  var query = url;
  var result = {};
  if (query == undefined){ 
     return result;
}
  query.split("&").forEach(function(part) {
    var item = part.split("=");
    result[item[0]] = decodeURIComponent(item[1]);
  });
  return result;
}
function doGet(e){
  const ctCompl = 'ct_completed';
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEET_KEY);
  var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var row = [];  
  if(typeof e !== undefined){
     mArr =  getJsonFromUrl(e.queryString);            
    for (i in mArr) if( i == ctCompl) {
      row.push(convTimeLong(mArr[i]));
    } else
        row.push(mArr[i]);
     sheet.appendRow(row); 
     } else {
     sheet.appendRow(['e undefined!']); 
    }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  return handleResponse(e)
}
function convTimeLong(dateTime) {  
  let  d = new Date();  
  let  dt=dateTime.replace('+', 'T'); 
    try { 
      var res = Utilities.formatDate(d,"GMT+2", "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
      return res
        } catch(e){
    return  dateTime;  } 
}
```

executions dashboard show status "completed' everywhere, execution time longest - 1.688 s
Client has set delay 5 second between call's, right now I don't now is percent of lost postback's decreased after delay was set or not, but it still very high.

https://youtu.be/0_H_mVAbp4g

Comment: How are you calling this?

Comment: Hello Marti!  Script deployed as WebApp, postback initialized from  https://zvonok.com/ru-ua/guide/guide_postback/   on every call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, using Google Sheets as a database is a bad idea. It's not designed for this so it could fail really bad. Using a proper database will make everything much, much easier. If you are using the spreadsheet to then cook the data, I'd advise to use a function that imports data like `IMPORTXML` ([see reference](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en)).

That being said, if you insist on using Sheets, you could try using locks:

```js
function appendRow(sheet, row) {
  const lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  while (!lock.tryLock(100000)) /* Spin the lock until it gets aquired */;
  try {
    sheet.appendRow(row)
    SpreadsheetApp.flush()
  } finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

To use it, you only need to pass the sheet and the values to add: `sheet.appendRow(row)` to `appendRow(sheet, row)`.

It will make sure that entries don't get overridden. Note that this will slow down the code a lot and the script can time out if there are a lot of requests.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I knew about lock, "Spreadsheet not designed" You mean for too often requests? Or maybe long query string after "?"

Comment: It's not meant to be used as a WebApp backend in general. Sure, you _can_ use it, but the developers didn't made it thinking you could use it this way, so there'll always be some problem. Also note that even [GCP free tier](https://cloud.google.com/free) has a (NoSQL) database that would work better than this (note that I've never actually used it).